# JS prevent flickered input border on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a custom input number. The only problem I have is that when I click on the button multiple times (increment), I'm getting a flickered input border.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 input.focus();
 const value = input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
 input.value = value + 1;
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus {
 border: 1px solid red;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">

<button>Increment</button>
```

There is a way to getting around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your button is taking focus when it is clicked. To prevent this happening, you can intercept the `mousedown` event on your button and call `preventDefault()`.

However, forcing focus like this is a strange thing to do and best avoided.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

const buttonEl = document.querySelector('button');
buttonEl.addEventListener('mousedown', ev => ev.preventDefault()) 
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
 input.focus();
 const value = input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
 input.value = value + 1;
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:focus, input:active {
 border: 1px solid red;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">

<button>Increment</button>
```

Comment: Why strange? check every custom number input and see this behavior.

Comment: @undefined In terms of a11y, if I have tabbed to focus on your button, hitting space or enter would move focus from the button. This would be unexpected and undesired.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 input.focus();
 const value = input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
 input.value = value + 1;
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid red;
 outline: none;
}

input:focus {
 border: 1px solid red;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">

<button>Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `border` and `padding` for input

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 input.focus();
 const value = input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
 input.value = value + 1;
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  border:1px solid #777777;
  padding:2px 0px;
}


input:focus {
  border:1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">

<button>Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the elements you can use the adjacent sibling selector `button:active + input` to select the input styles while the button is being pressed. However to re-align things you will need to use a container and grid (or I'm sure you can pull this off with flex or just floats)

CSS Grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Adjacent Sibling Selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 input.focus();
 const value = input.value ? parseFloat(input.value) : 0;
 input.value = value + 1;
})
```

```css
body {
 margin: 50px;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

button:active + input, 
input:focus {
 border: 1px solid red;
 outline: none;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.container input {
  order: 1;
}
.container button {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button>Increment</button>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```